# Remove Object if Key Value don't match Input Variable after calculating and comparing with input variables

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to compare input variable key/values with data in Json file, there are 200+ orders in the file, for Order_number (66 in this case) need to calculate and compare the count of line items(6 in this case) along with the Quantity of items(7 in this case), if it doesn't match need to remove Object Refund along with its elements, else leave it as it is.

The variables from the sql query result to be compared against this sample would be :
Order_number 66
count of line items 6
Quantity of items 6

I got stuck at calculating it.

File Content:

```
{
"app_id": 111,
"fulfillments": [],
"line_items": [
    {
        "id": 376,
        "quantity": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 992,
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 929,
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 768,
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 929,
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 768,
        "quantity": 1
    }
],
"name": "#59",
"number": 6,
"order_number": 66,
"order_id": 999,

]
```

}

```
var derivedOrderNumber = getVariable("Trans_ID", "");
var derivedNumberOfLineItems = getVariable("Count_Of_Fulfillment", "");
var derivedTotalQuantityOfItems = getVariable("Total_Quantity", "");
var jsonOrderNumber = 0;
var jsonNumberOfLineItems = 0;
var jsonTotalQuantityOfItems = 0;

//Calculate Number of Line Items and Total Quantity for order_number

 let output = arr.reduce((op,cur)=>{
  if(op[cur['ORDER_NUMBER']]){
    op[cur['LINE_ITEMS']]['jsonTotalQuantityOfItems']+=cur['QUANTITY'];
    op[cur['LINE_ITEMS']]['jsonNumberOfLineItems']++;
  } else {
       op[cur['ORDER_NUMBER']] ={
        'jsonNumberOfLineItems' : 1,
        'jsonTotalQuantityOfItems' : cur['QUANTITY'],
       }
  }
return op;
},{})
console.log(output);
```

Comment: You need to mind capitalization. `order_number` is not the same as `ORDER_NUMBER`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let arrSum = 0;
data.line_items.forEach((element) => {
  arrSum += element.quantity;
});
if (arrSum != data.number) delete data.refunds;
```